# Using php in a javascript

Tags: javascript, php

this is a problem. its not working. im making a timer before redirecting.
is any wrong about my code?

```
     <script>
        var base_url ="https://www.mydomain.com/";
        var redirect = "<?php echo $redirect; ?>";
        var targetURL= base_url.concat(redirect);
        //change the second to start counting down from
        var countdownfrom=9;


        var currentsecond=document.redirect.redirect2.value=countdownfrom+1;
        function countredirect(){
            if (currentsecond!==1){
                currentsecond-=1;
                document.redirect.redirect2.value=currentsecond;
            }
            else{
                window.location=targetURL;
                return;
            }
            setTimeout("countredirect()",1000);
        }

        countredirect();
        //-->
     </script>
```

Comment: debug `targetURL` I bet it looks something like.. `"https://www.new-i-ching.com/<?php echo $redirect; ?>"`

Comment: Any error exception?

Comment: What is the rendered JS after it goes through the PHP parser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript I suggest you read up on how to properly pass a PHP variable to JavaScript

Comment: What is the value of variable `$redirect` ?

Comment: Doesn't matter, it's a string, as is

Comment: Remove the quotation marks and parentheses on the callback in your setTimeout call: `setTimeout(countredirect, 1000);` And make sure its a PHP file and not something else.

Comment: @Jite not quite, that is the same is simply invoking the function immediately. Properly would be `setTimeout(countredirect,1000);`, or passing a function reference to the timeout. Or use an anonymous function wrapper

Comment: @SterlingArcher you are right, I just woke up, so i missed the parentheses ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
<script>
var base_url ="https://www.mydomain.com/";
<?php echo 'var redirect = "'.$redirect.'";'; ?>
..
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is ok?